# How to match photos to reference colors in batch?

Tags: photo-editing, color, batch, software-recommendation

I have a photo of a paint tin and a list of images with reference colors for the color of the paint to be adjusted to.

How can this be done? Can it be automated to be done in batch?

[image: paint can]

Comment: It's unclear, at least to me, which way you are trying to match. Are you trying to change the other images to match the single image, or are you trying to produce multiple versions of the single image to match each of the multiple reference shots? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: I'm trying to produce multiple colored versions of the single image of the paint tin to match the reference colors!

Comment: When you adjust the color, ALL pixels will get changed.  What looks to you like a single color of paint is actually a continuum of colors “near” the paint color. What you are really looking to do, I believe, is mask an area, desaturate it to grayscale and then produce copies with the grayscale parts colorized in a variety of colors, while leaving the rest of the image alone.  You might e able to do this with ImageMagick, but I don’t know for sure.  It would help if you would post a sample image.

Comment: I added a sample picture of the colored paint in the tin to my post!
So I basically need a round selection that is being colorized in the colors of the reference chart. I thought I might be able to do this with photoshop actions, but until now I haven't found a working solucion yet!

Comment: What non working solutions have you found? Can you explain what you have tried?

Comment: The answer will probably Photoshop because this is a software recommendation question. But what you need to achieve, is totally obscure to me.

Comment: I guess what you want to change is the 'Hue' of the circular area inside the tin. You can select that circle, split it into HSL (Hue/Saturation/Lightness), and then change the Hue number to a fixed number for each color you want to show. Potentially, the other two need adjustements too, but they cannot be set fixed, but need relative offsets (or you lose all shadows and details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be done with **ImageMagick**. You will need to use an image editor, such as Photoshop or GIMP, to create the following two images:

- One to mask out the paint contained in the paint can.
- Another to reproduce the shadows from the paint can onto the paint.

The image of the paint can, the paint mask, the shadows, and the color swatches can then be composed to produce a variation of the image with a different color. Use the image editor to figure out what order and blending modes to use for the layers.

Then you can call ImageMagick in a loop to reproduce the results for each of the desired color swatches. (See [ImageMagick v6 Examples: Compositing Images](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/).)